# Problem in using getter function from a class object that gets value through singleSnapshot . Android,Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, getter

I am extracting data entered by the user from firebase through a singleSnapshot(stored in an 'Advertisement' class object).

The **getter** method for product name works,but getProductDescription() returns a null value, I don't know why. i.e, textView14 is filled and not textView15.

The data has been uploaded correctly in the firebase console.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);


       // productImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        //productDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView15);

       final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       DatabaseReference reff;

        productName =  v.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        productDescription = v.findViewById(R.id.textView15);

        reff = database.getReference();
        reff.child("Advertisement").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot;

                    Advertisement advertisement = snapshot.child("adv").getValue(Advertisement.class);
                    productName.setText(advertisement.getProductName());
                    productDescription.setText( advertisement.getProductDescription());

                }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
       return v;
```

}

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TFef.png)

> This is the firebase console

```
    package in.revmeup.revmeup;
import androidx.annotation.Keep;

@Keep
public class Advertisement {
    private String productName;
    private String productDescription;
    private String productImageUrl;
    public Advertisement(String productDescription)
    {
        this.productName=productName;
        this.productImageUrl=productImageUrl;
        this.productDescription=productDescription;
    }
    public Advertisement()
    {
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Advertisement{" +
                "product_Name='" + productName + '\'' +
                ", product_Image_URL='" + productImageUrl + '\'' +
                ", product_Description='" + productDescription +
                '}';
    }
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public String getProductImageUrl() {
        return productImageUrl;
    }

    public void setProductImageUrl(String productImageUrl) {
        this.productImageUrl = productImageUrl;
    }
}
```

Please help me rectify this issue. It bugs me especially because one function works and the other doesn't and they are of the same object.

Comment: Please add the content of your `Advertisement` class.

Comment: I've added it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been rectified.. I had not added an Object of Advertisement class to the database, but a hashmap value(that code bit was in another Java file and I totally didn't consider that). It was an interesting(and silly on my side) mistake but no regrets about my first stackoverflow question!